# Relation between infimum of function in segment and subsegment

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$.

How to prove that $\inf\limits_{[a,b]} f=\min\{\inf\limits_{[a,c]} f,\inf\limits_{[c,b]} f\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\inf_{[x,y]} f \ge \inf_{[a,b]} f$ for any $a \le x \le y \le b$ we have 
$\inf_{[a,b]} f \le \min(\inf_{[a,c]} f,\inf_{[c,b]} f)$.

Now suppose $\epsilon>0$, then there is some $x \in [a,b]$ such that
$f(x) < \inf_{[a,b]} f + \epsilon$. Since either $x \in [a,c]$ or $x \in [c,b]$ (or both) we have
$\min(\inf_{[a,c]} f,\inf_{[c,b]} f) \le f(x) <  \inf_{[a,b]} f + \epsilon$.
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Comment: Dear copper.hat! If $x\in [a,c)$ then why $\min(\inf_{[a,c]} f,\inf_{[c,b]} f) \le f(x) $?

Comment: Let $x\in[a,c]$ but $x\notin [c,b]$ then $\inf \limits_{[a,c]}f\leqslant f(x)<\inf \limits_{[a,b]}f+\epsilon$. But why $\inf \limits_{[c,b]}f\leqslant f(x)<\inf \limits_{[a,b]}f+\epsilon$? I think that $\inf \limits_{[c,b]}f$ can be greater than $f(x)$. Can you explain that moment what you wrote in detail please?

Comment: @RFZ: It can, but $\min(x,y)$ is less than or equal to both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ohhh right! Sorry for stupid question, Thanks a lot! By the way very nice solution:)